# Control the Error from Meta class in Django model

Tags: python, django, model

I'm working with Blog website with Django, I have a model called **Post** and its like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    txt = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.user} {self.title}"
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']
        unique_together = ['title', 'txt']
```

and so when a user try to create more than one Post with the same title and text it must launch an Error, but I don't know how to control this error and turn it into a proper Error and code will launch the **Constraint_failed** error and I wanna control this kind of Errors not just in the Admin panel but in the User client side that User can see his mistakes and fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this problem by validating the user input data. To do this, you can create a Django model form or use a regular Django form, depending on your choice.

**forms.py**

```py
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'txt']

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        title = cleaned_data.get('title')
        txt = cleaned_data.get('txt')

        if title and txt:
            existing_post = Post.objects.filter(title=title, txt=txt).exists()
            if existing_post:
                raise forms.ValidationError("A post with the same title and text already exists.")

        return cleaned_data
```